# Log the dimensions of an ALAssetRepresentation

Tags: objective-c, alassetslibrary

How do you log the dimensions of an image?

My Code:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *asset = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
NSLog(@"dim: %@", [asset dimensions]);
```

I've tried lots of variations but keep getting format warnings which require CGSize (aka 'struct CGSize')

Answer (score 0):

```
ALAssetRepresentation *asset = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
NSLog(@"dim: %@", NSStringFromCGSize([asset dimensions]));
```